# Cannot extract merged .osm.pbf OSRM file using docker

Tags: docker, leaflet, wsl-2, osrm, leaflet-routing-machine

I merged the following .pbf countries I have extracted from geofabric(using osmosis):
Italy, Slovenia, Croatia, Bosnia, Montenegro, Albania.

The order I merged them:

Italy&Slovenia

Croatia&Bosnia

Monenegro&Albania

then merged the results of this merges and created a single file from this named ambcsi.osm.pbf

While trying to extract the final result 2.13GB size with the following command:

```
docker run -t -v C:/Users/Eka/Desktop/pbfFilesTestM:/pbfFilesTestM osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /pbfFilesTestM/ambcsi.osm.pbf
```

the process starts but it stops without any response. Upon searching I found out that you can configure the .wslconfig file giving more ram for this specific process which I did I created the .wslconfig file and added this:

```
[wsl2]
memory=16GB
processors=6
```

It's all my PC has. Still not able to finish the process. Someone else  said that it might not be necessary because docker calculates the amount of power it needs for a specific operation. My laptop has the following configuration: Core i7 10th gen 2.60ghz 16GB ram 6 cores is this enough for a 2.13GB .pbf file? Am I doing something wrong? Should I configure better the .wslconfig file? Or is the way I merged the files wrong and not a best practice ? O is simply my laptop's configuration not up to the task ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this after some digging and reading this thread in GitHub:https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/314

about almost the same problem as me they clearly state the bigger the .pbf file is the more processing power it needs to perform the operation and I tested yesterday with a merged file of 1.85GB and it was going well so in my case it had nothing to do with the .wslconfig file so for my file of 2.13GB it definitely requires more RAM so yeah :\ .